# A sequence of more than one item is not allowed as the first argument of fn:generate-id() (<Records>, <Records>)

Tags: xslt

I am trying to group the XML segments based on  two XML field values (GroupPolicyNumber & ParticipantIdentifier)and written below XSLT code. but getting error :

A sequence of more than one item is not allowed as the first argument of fn:generate-id() (, )

```
<xsl:for-each select="Records[generate-id() = generate-id(key('groups',  concat(GroupPolicyNumber, '|', ParticipantIdentifier)))]">
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, the correct expression is:

```
<xsl:for-each select="Records[generate-id() = generate-id(key('groups',  concat(GroupPolicyNumber, '|', ParticipantIdentifier))[1])]">
```

However, you will not get that error unless (1) you're using an XSLT 2.0 (or higher) processor **and** (2) your stylesheet is tagged as `version="2.0"` (or higher). So this raises the question why are you trying to use Muenchian grouping instead of the built-in `xsl:for-each-group` method.

Comment: 'you will not get that error unless (1) you're using an XSLT 2.0 (or higher) processor and (2) your stylesheet is tagged as version="2.0"': if the XSLT 2 or 3 processor doesn't support XPath 1.0 backwards compatible processing then it can raise the error even with `version="1.0"` in the stylesheet.

Comment: To expand on this correct answer, in XPath 1.0, functions like `contains()`, `generate-id()`, `substring()` allowed you to supply a node-set as the first argument, and ignored all but the first node. In XPath 2.0, it's an error if you supply more than one node, so you have to supply the `[1]` predicate explicitly. But rather than do the simple fix to make this work with 2.0, it would be better to rewrite it to use new 2.0 grouping constructs, which give more readable code and are quite likely tto be more efficient.